# Can not filter the data from as per date using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I need one help.I need to filter data from list as per two date using Angular.js.My all code are present inside [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/uDNVGibiHmDTAMD9LgAh?p=preview).There you can find i have list of 3 set of data.On the to i have two date field one is for `from date` and another is for `to date`. If user is selecting two date the list data will filter accordingly means the list data should view as per selecting dates from date field.Here i can not get that type of result.[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/uDNVGibiHmDTAMD9LgAh?p=preview) is code.Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In script.js at line 25 change

`getMidnight(event.date + 24 * 3600 * 1000).getTime()`

to

`getMidnight(new Date(event.date) + 24 * 3600 * 1000).getTime()`

Edit:

For the comment, add these two line before `return events.filter`

`from = getMidnight(from);`

`to = getMidnight(to).getTime() + (24 * 3600-1) * 1000;`

Comment: ok,at least list data are coming.But it should include the selecting date record also.If i am choosing `2016-05-21 to 2016-05-22` the result is only coming for `2016-05-22` where it should come for two date also.

Comment: did you mean you want to filter date between 2016-05-21 00:00:00 to 2016-05-22 23:59:59 ?

Comment: yes,it those two date will selected then all record in between two date and including those two date also should display.